# How to identify specific text from file upload

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a function to read row by row from a .txt file which is received from html.
Now I need to filter out things that are not needed and it will be inserted into an array.
How do I create a (if else statement) to recognize certain text?
Example between [info] echo:1080 and [info] Executing: |echo | ${result} |  |
I like to get the identifer to recognize [info] echo:1080.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

in first you must crawled in text and fetch all of [info] tags in text and push theme in array and with a foreach loop you can analys the code ,
e.g : in foreach you getting :
foreach($array,$item)
{
     ...
}
$item=echo:1080
in above you can explode $item with ':' character
 $item=explode(':',$item);

now you have 2 value that one is an string and other one is executing command for e.g 'echo'

then you must use 'eval' function to execute you code

$command=$item[0].' '.'"'.$item[1].'"';
eval($command);

i hope this solution will be help you